# Neo4j gem https with self-signed certificate

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, neo4j

I have a question about self-signed SSL certificates.

I'm getting Neo4j running on AWS, and want to connect my heroku machines to the AWS DB (via a load balancer), but I want to do it via HTTPS, and I'm wanting to use a self-signed certificate.

While I'm aware of how to configure the server side, I would also like to ensure that the client side uses the same certificate for secure communication. Is there some configuration where I can specify my public certificate key to ensure that connections are secure (and no man-in-the-middle attack is possible)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Neo4j settings.

```
# Certificate location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.cert.location=<path_to_certificate>

# Private key location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.key.location=<path_to_key>
```

Here is more information - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/security-server.html#security-server-https

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MicTech - It might not have been clear in my question, but I'm actually referring to the client end of things - ensuring that the client is configured to also recognise the certificate as the official certificate. Have fixed up my question to make more clear ;)